# How can I upload an image file to a php background script, i.e, using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, upload

I am trying to upload an image file using ajax to the server. However, till now i have only transported data to the background php script using ajax. I haven't done so with files.However, I am trying as follows:-

```
     <form id="imageUploadForm" action="profileThis.php" method="POST"
       enctype="multipart/formdata"> 

         <input  type="file" id="boozeImgFile" name="boozeImgFile" >  

         <input type="button" onclick="uploadImage()" value="Upload">

    </form>
```

And my ajax code is as follows

```
      $("imageUploadForm").request(
       {
         method:'post',

         parameters:{category:$("category").value, categoryId:$("categoryId").value, userId:

         $("userInSession").value, uploadImage:'true'}, 

         onComplete:function()
         {
           alert("successfully uploaded to profilethis.php");

         },

         onSuccess:function(ajax)
         {
           alert(ajax.responseText);      

          },

         onFailure:ajaxFailure,

         onException:ajaxFailure
      });
```

However, when I am trying to retrieve it in my background script using `$filename=$_FILES["boozeImgFile"]["name"]` its not working

My profileThis.php looks like this

```
       if(isset($_REQUEST['uploadImage']))
       { 
         $name=$_FILES["boozeImgFile"]["name"];        

         $tempName=$_FILES["boozeImgFile"]["tmp_name"];

         $size=$_FILES["boozeImgFile"]["size"];

         $type=$_FILES["boozeImgFile"]["type"];

         if(($type=="image/jpg"||$type=="image/jpeg"||$type=="image/pjpeg")&&         ($size>0&&$size<=4096000))
         {
        $userId=clearSpecialChars($_REQUEST['userId']);

                $tempName=$_FILES["boozeImgFile"]["tmp_name"];

            $category=clearSpecialChars($_REQUEST['category']);

            $categoryId=clearSpecialChars($_REQUEST['categoryId']);

               $name="img_".$userId."_".$filename;


               $rootDir="C:/xampp/htdocs";

               $dir="/boozeimg/".$category."/".$categoryId;

               $fullDirectory=$rootDir.$dir;

               $realPath=$dir."/".$name;

               $fullPath=$rootDir.$dir."/".$name;


       if(is_dir($fullDirectory))
       {
        move_uploaded_file($tempName, $fullPath);

       }
       else
       {
        mkdir($fullDirectory,0777,true);

        move_uploaded_file($tempName, $fullPath);

       }
     }
```

In profileThis.php the first line inside the if condition doesn't reach, however the if condition by itself does reach

Comment: I have edited it. You can check it now.

Comment: I see you set `$name = ...` near the start, and use `$filename` near the middle -- but I can't find any assignments to `$filename`. Is this the mistake? `$tempName` is assigned twice, but it looks like the same value in both assignments. Make sure `$userId` and `$filename` don't have "special characters" in them, either. (If the filename or userid is `../../../../../Windows/System 32/....` what could the consequences be? Probably unhappy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the quick answer is you can't. You can't use AJAX to upload files.  What you can do is have the target of a form be a hidden iframe and submit your form to that.  It is essentially the same thing in result, but technically completely different.  Most people still use the term ajax (including my forthcoming url), but it's definitely not ajax.  Here's a link with a short tutorial:

http://www.coursesweb.net/ajax/upload-images

Comment: You can using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) API, but note it works with new browsers only (i.e. IE 10+)

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using a cool jQuery plugin called [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).  It might seem a little complicated if you don't understand all parts of the process, but the website has decent documentation/examples and overall it's a really cool plugin.